# How to update a user profile field using rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-auth

I am new to django and very confused. I am using django as the backend API for my angular application.

I want to add few more details to the User model so I added the following to my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I am using an application to add rest authentication support: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth

Using this application I can edit a users profile with this URL doing a POST request: `http://localhost:8080/rest-auth/user/`

**Question**

How can I update the custom field `company_name`? while editing a users profile?

**What I've tried**

I tried to override the `UserDetailsSerializer` that the [application provides](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L41) but it isn't having any effect. 
This is what I tried adding to my applications `serializers.py`

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('company_name',)

class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')
```

Comment: Generally, in REST APIs you can do a PUT request, using JSON of the updated model.

Comment: override UserDetailsSerializer update method.

Comment: @levi how would I do that? I tried creating `serializers.py` in my application but doesn't seem to be having an effect. This is my first django application so I'm more lost...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django rest framework, then you basically want to have an update method on your view class for UserProfile that takes in the user id as a request param. Then in that method you want to use the ORM to get a model object for the given userprofile id, set the property that was also passed as a param, and save the changed model object. Then generate a success response and return it.

You can read more about how to do this here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/